# QueryDSL fetch joins requests GROUP BY without groupby

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I want to eagerly get nested associations with QueryDSL using fetch join.

This query works brilliantly:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select player from Player player " +
                "left outer join fetch player.encryptions encryption " +
                "left outer join fetch encryption.result result " +
                "left outer join fetch encryption.question question " +
                "where player.nickName = :nickName ")
                .setParameter("nickName", nickName)
                .getSingleResult();
```

but this one (written on QueryDSL)

```
queryFactory.from(qPlayer)
                .leftJoin(qPlayer.encryptions, qEncryption).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(qEncryption.result, qResult).fetchJoin()
                .leftJoin(qEncryption.question).fetchJoin()
                .where(qPlayer.nickName.eq(nickName))
                .select(Projections.constructor(PlayerScore.class, qPlayer, qResult.pointsAmount.sum()))
                .fetchOne();
```

for some magic reason requests group by clause despite I don't even use it.

To be more specific, QueryDSL request falls with such an exception:

```
ERROR: column "player0_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

These two code snippets produces slightly different SQL queries. The QueryDSL has two additional fragments in `select` clause:

```
select
player0_.id as col_0_0_,
sum(result2_.points_amount) as col_1_0_,
...
```

The `player0_.id` is duplicated and I think it's the reason why it fails. I also think that's QueryDSL bug.

Comment: I never used QueryDSL - but I see this `.leftJoin(qEncryption.question).fetchJoin()` is different form to `.leftJoin(qEncryption.result, qResult).fetchJoin()` are you missing something like qQuestion or something in the qEncryption.question fetch?

Comment: Not really. I miss it because I don't need any alias for question. Alias for result used few lines below.

Comment: if you don't need the alias, that means you don't use it, so why do you have it?

Comment: I think it's the `sum()` aggregate function that enforces a GROUP BY.
Sometimes operations are implicitly performed by QDSL. E.g. joining, when you use the given table's columns in a `where()` function, doesn't have to be declared.